# Maxscale: maxctrl error when admin_ssl parameters are set in maxscale.cnf

Tags: mariadb, ssl-certificate, maxscale

System:

- Maxscale 2.5.9
- Ubuntu 20.04

In order to access the Web AdminGUI my maxsclale.cnf file looks like this:

```
[maxscale]
threads=auto
admin_host=0.0.0.0
admin_secure_gui=1
admin_auth=1
admin_enabled=1
admin_gui=1
admin_ssl_key=/etc/ssl/certs/maxscale-key.pem
admin_ssl_cert=/etc/ssl/certs/maxscale-cert.pem
admin_ssl_ca_cert=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

[...all other configuration..]
```

With this configuration I can access the Web-AdminGUI on port 8989 from the internal ip address (not 127.0.0.1) by browser.
The SSL key/certs are self-signed .

BUT
When using the command line like:

```
maxctrl list servers
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Error: socket hang up
```

When I remove or comment out the lines with the *admin_ssl_XXX* parameters and restart maxscale, command line works again, but of course the Web-AdminGUI does not.

I tried with various SSL certificate creations (also the one that is listed on the mariadb.com-Website
https://mariadb.com/docs/security/encryption/in-transit/create-self-signed-certificates-keys-openssl/#create-self-signed-certificates-keys-openssl),
the issue remains.

No errors in the maxscale.log whatsoever.

What is the best way to debug this issue?
Or do you have by any chance the right answer at hand?

YOUR help is greatly appreciated!

BR. Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `maxctrl --secure` to encrypt the connections used by it.

Since you are using self-signed certificates, you have to also specify the CA certificate with `--tls-ca-cert=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` if it's not installed in the system certificate store.

In addition, you probably need to use `--tls-verify-server-cert=false` to disable any warnings about self-signed certificates.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. With the two parameters I get an error **self signed certificate**. So I do have to figure how to create self-signed certs that will be accepted by maxctrl. BR. Martin

Comment: I've added a clarification on what options can be used to ignore warnings about self-signed certificates.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I still get the error **Error: self signed certificate**... Crated also new SSL certs (self-signed), but error persists :-(